# How to decompress an archive with Phar immediately after compressing it?

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to write a class that should create an archive and compress it and/or decompress a compressed archive.

Creating an archive and then compressing it or decompressing a compressed archive separately are no problem.

But if I do them immediately after each other phar thinks that the old archive file still exists but since I removed that file with unlink it actually does not exist anymore.

So can anyone explain why the following example fails ?

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Unable to add newly
> converted phar
> "test.tar" to the list
> of phars, a phar with that name already exists

```
mkdir("test");
file_put_contents("test/a", "testa");
file_put_contents("test/b", "testb");

$phar = new PharData("test.tar");
$phar->buildFromDirectory('test');
$phar->compress(Phar::GZ);

unset($phar);
unlink("test.tar");

$phar = new PharData("test.tar.gz");
$phar->decompress();
```

Comment: Is this specific to PHP 7.4?

Comment: @Dharman not exactly but It was only tested with php 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the archive still resides in memory so it's not enough to remove it from the file system.

The Phar class provides the static method `Phar::unlinkArchive`
to do this.

Also note that you have to close all file handles to `test.tar` before removing it with `Phar::unlinkArchive`, this can be done with unsetting the object holding the file handle with `unset($phar)`

So the following modifies the above example to use `Phar::unlinkArchive` :

```
mkdir("test");
file_put_contents("test/a", "testa");
file_put_contents("test/b", "testb");

$phar = new PharData("test.tar");

$phar->buildFromDirectory('test');

$phar->compress(Phar::GZ);

unset($phar);
Phar::unlinkArchive("test.tar");

$phar = new PharData("test.tar.gz");
$phar->decompress();
```